# Inhibit Storyboard Segue from performing segue action

Tags: uistoryboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

**Question**
How do I deny a storyboard segue from taking place?

**Context:**
I have a static grouped table view of options on the first view controller that is visible (the main menu if you will).

I purposely show the UI early to give the user a chance to interact and perceive a fast load response. Other operations that might be importing data for example, happen on a background operation queue. Most of my UI functions are in fact, ready to go as soon as you see them.

One menu item (table row) in particular though, isn't ready until some data is imported (I send a notification when all is ready).

While I could remove the storyboard segue for this action, it got me thinking on how I might inhibit a segue from firing because a certain condition wasn't met.

I'll likely allow the segue in practice, and have the destination view controller limit initialization until it receives the notification it is waiting for.

But can one intercept a segue and stop it, programmatically?

Comment: For future readers without the iOS 5.0 requirement, on iOS 6.0 you can use -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]

Comment: Indeed, a lot of time has passed since I needed this, and going forward, needing such control in an iOS6 and later context, your suggestion Jon, using the new delegate method is exactly the right answer. I'm going to remove the iOS5 tag on this question. You should then answer it formally, which I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS 6.0 and later, you can prevent a segue from firing after the action that would normally trigger it has occurred by overriding the -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:] method and returning NO.

Answer (score 1):

You could do a programatic segue where instead using a segue from the controller itself and then you do the segue using performSegueWithIdentifier and then you could test for this particular segue and decide to do it or not.

Comment: In your approach, the segue isn't attached to a button or table cell. It may as well be manual. I'd like to leave the original segue in place in the storyboard; it's a form of documentation of intent. What I'm really trying to find is a way to deny a segue at runtime. Much like old school delegate callbacks that returned a BOOL that either allowed or disallowed the action. From the API, it seems like there really isn't a way to do this. One has to commit to the segue and handle things downstream or not use SB segues.

Comment: That is correct what I was saying would work and would show a segue in the storyboard but it would come from controller not the button/table cell etc.  This would do exactly what you want. However if you want to leave it then I don't know of a way to stop the seque.  You could also just let it go to the view and if the data is not ready you could use a message or spinner or something to let them know the data is still loading.

Comment: What you're suggesting has no target-action binding right on the control (button, table cell) in question; it is a named segue I call in code after some other IBAction complaint method I create and connect, gets called. It's a good alternative to a direct binding, but my specific question is whether there's a way to intercept and deny a directly bound segue.

Comment: I know of no code to just "stop/cancel" the segue.  However what I have is a tableviewcontroller with a staic tables of grouped cells, 3 of them.  Then a segue from that tableviewcontroller to the uiviewcontroller that the cells will take me to.  When the cells is clicked then I use didSelectRowAtIndexPath and decide which row was selected and then use code to perform the segue and of course can do any kind of testing etc here before I decide if I should or should not do the segue

Comment: - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellText = selectedCell.textLabel.text;   
    if ([cellText isEqualToString:@"Cell1"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
    } else if ([cellText isEqualToString:@"Cell2"]) {
        //do test to decide if you should segue or not
    } else if ([cellText isEqualToString:@"Cell3"]) {
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"segue1" sender:self];
    }
}

Comment: I think this is the best answer for iOS 5.0. For iOS 6.0+, you can use -[UIViewController shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:sender:]

Answer (score 0):

You could subclass UIStoryboardSegue as described in its [reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIStoryboardSegue_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

A possible implementation:

.h

```
@interface MYPushNoAnimationSegue : UIStoryboardSegue
@end
```

.m

```
#import "MYPushNoAnimationSegue.h"

@implementation MYPushNoAnimationSegue

- (void)perform {
    if (condition) {
        [[(UIViewController *)self.sourceViewController navigationController] pushViewController:self.destinationViewController animated:NO];
    }
}

@end
```

That being done, you can select your existing segue in the storyboard, then set its style to custom, and enter MYPushNoAnimationSegue to the Segue Class in the Attributes inspector.

I know a lot of time passed, maybe you already solved it, but it might help others who face the same problem.